# What should I do if I have have budget for Off Page Optimization?

Tags: seo, google, local-seo

What should I do for Off Page Optimization if I have a budget like 500$. **My target is increasing the organic traffic.**

I thought following things.

1. Google Adwords : I think that Google Adwords nothing to do with SEO. So I forget it.
2. Facebook Advertising : Same as point 01. So I thought it is also not useful for increasing organic traffic.
3. Guest Post Writing : Generally writing a quality 2000 -3000 word post is about 100$. So I can publish only 5 posts only. I think it is also not cheap. ROI will be really bad (As R(return) I mean increasing organic traffic).

So what are the big sites do for off page optimization? I mean when I am investing 500$ for off page optimization I am expect, increasing fair number of organic traffic.

Or is it a bad idea for investing money for Off Page Optimization?

Note : If answer is depend on the nature of the website ,this is for a web design and development company official site.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad and opinion-based for our specific question & answer format, and will lead to [open-ended discussions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad idea to invest for the long term quality result. But investment shouldn't involve buying links.

Guest post is nearly dead unless you use in some creative way.

**AdWords & Facebook Ad:**

- It doesn't have any impact on SEO as off-site optimisation.
- But, you can be more creative and possibly you can use some budget on advertising to bring more quality traffic to your website. If your content will have the strength then people will link naturally.

**Other Options**

- You can also use the budget to get some videos done which is a great way to engage.

**Note:** There are so many things can be done on the website to build quality content, so i would say your prime focus should be the website and then use your budget in a creative manner to build more natural links.